# why does my objective c code keep saying data argument not used by format string

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

```
-(void) timerRun{
    secondsCount = secondsCount - 1;
    int minuts = secondsCount /60;
    int seconds = secondsCount - (minuts * 60);

    NSString *timerOutput = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%2d:.2d" , minuts, seconds];
    countdownLabel.text = timerOutput;

    if (secondsCount == 0) {
        [countdownTimer invalidate];
        countdownLabel = nil;
    }
}
```

Xcode is telling me in the `NSString` line that data argument not used by format string and every time I try to run my timer all that appears is: `2d:.2d`
Will someone who knows Objective C well please look over my code.

Comment: Because the data argument is not used by the format string.  Generally, you should have as many arguments as you have `%` characters (though there are a few exceptions).

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a percent sign there, buddy.

`NSString *timerOutput = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%2d:.2d" , minuts, seconds];`

`.2d` isn't a replacement spec.